# pushViewController not working with tab bar controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, pushviewcontroller

I am trying to push in a new view controller with the code:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
```

But its not working. This code happens when you select a cell in my table view. I have a table view which I think is preventing this from happening. I have tried presenting it modally but that gets rid of the navigation bar and i can't go back. There is an extremely similar to this but the answer didn't work for me!

UPDATE

```
- (void)loadView {
    // Create an instance of UIWebView as large as the screen
    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];
    // Tell web view to scale web content to fit within bounds of webview 
    [wv setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [self setView:wv];
    [wv release];
}
```

puts the web view as the WebViewController's view

there is no nib as shown above

the didSelect cell method IS CALLED using an NSLog to find out

Everything is initialized and allocated and non-zero

UPDATE:

my did select cell method:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Push the web view controller onto the navigaton stack - this implicity
    // creates the web view controller's view the first time through

    NSLog(@"TOUCHED!");

    webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] init];

    if (webViewController == nil) {
        NSLog(@"webViewController in nil state");
    }

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];


    // Grab the selected item
    RSSItem *entry = [[channel items] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Construct a URL with the link string of the item
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[entry link]];

    // Construct a request object with that URL
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    // Load the request into the web view
    [[webViewController webView] loadRequest:req];

    // Set the title of the web view controller's navigation item
    [[webViewController navigationItem] setTitle:[entry title]];

}
```

ALL OF THIS WORKED BEFORE INSERTING TAB BAR CONTROLLER

UPDATE

Where I create the controllers (IN APP DELEGATE):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

             self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    ListViewController *lvc = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];

    [lvc autorelease];
    // Create the tabBarController
    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

    // Create two view controllers
    UIViewController *vc1 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[YoutubeViewController alloc] init];

    // Make an array containing the two view controllers
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil];

    // The viewControllers array retains vc1 and vc2, we can release
    // our ownership of them in this method
    [vc1 release];
    [vc2 release];

    // Attach them to the tab bar controller
    [tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];

    // Put the tabBarController's view on the window
    [[self window] setRootViewController:tabBarController];

    // The window retains tabBarController, we can release our reference
    [tabBarController release];

    // Show the window
    [[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

So I really have no idea whats going on here. Also IF YOU COULD PLEASE HELP ME WITH ANOTHER QUESTION! Go to my profile and see the question about how to stop cutoffs/add extra line for text label in uitableviewcell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see the initial UINavigationViewController in your app delegate. In order to use the self.navigationController pushViewController, the view controller needs to be in one of the self.navigationController.viewControllers. Can you modify your code and try the following and see it works for you.

```
// Create two view controllers
UIViewController *vc1 = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
UIViewController *vc2 = [[YoutubeViewController alloc] init];

// Create the UINavigationController and put the list view controller as the root view controller
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc1];

// Make an array containing the two view controllers and the UINavigationController which has the ListViewController is the first one.
NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navController, vc2, nil];

// The viewControllers array retains vc1 and vc2, we can release
// our ownership of them in this method
[vc1 release];
[vc2 release];
[navController release];

// Attach them to the tab bar controller
[tabBarController setViewControllers:viewControllers];
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several points you have to check, in order to make the push successful.

First, the view controller to be pushed is probably designed and stored in a NIB file. Check how you create it in your code, particularly the NIB file name (assuming you use `-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle`). It must be the real NIB filename without the NIB/XIB extension.

Second, is the selection event triggered and the message really sent to the table view delegate ? You could put some logging to ensure that. The table view won't prevent the view controller from being pushed on the navigation stack.

The question isn't really precise on how/where you create that controller, so finally, if none of this works, make the test to alloc/init the controller just before pushing. You might have a better understanding of what is going on.

Comment: no it is not a nib, it is a web view and i make it so in the loadView method:

Comment: - (void)loadView 

       {


    // Create an instance of UIWebView as large as the screen

    CGRect screenFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

    UIWebView *wv = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:screenFrame];

    // Tell web view to scale web content to fit within bounds of webview 

    [wv setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    
    [self setView:wv];

    [wv release];

     }

and then i load the request somewhere else 
the didSelect cell method IS CALLED using an nslog

Comment: but it doesn't have to be nib, before i put in the tab bar controller it worked with no nib

Answer (score 2):

If the view controller is under the "More" button, then things change a bit.

Here's what worked for me to figure out what navigation controller to use:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    UITabBarController *tabBar = (UITabBarController*) self.window.rootViewController;
    UINavigationController* navigationController = (UINavigationController*)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
    UIViewController* top = nil;
    if ([navigationController respondsToSelector:@selector(topViewController)]) {
        top = navigationController.topViewController;
    }

    // the actual current navigation controller depends on whether we are on a view under the More tab
    UINavigationController *curNavController;
    if (top == nil) {  // this implies a view under the More tab
        curNavController = tabBar.moreNavigationController;
    } else {
        curNavController = navigationController;
    }
    [[LocalNotificationMgr Get] ReceivedNotification:notif navController:curNavController];
}
```

Basically if the user is on a view under the More tab, the actual current UINavigationController you want to use to push a UIViewController onto is the UITabBarController's moreNavigationController property.
If on a view actually visible on the tab bar itself, use the UITabBarController's selectedViewController property.
NOTE: if you're on the "More screen" itself, you can use either property.

Comment: Note that "top" could be easily replaced by a plain boolean indicating if responds or not to the selector. Anyway, your solution worked for me. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Did you do it in the manner like below??

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(reqList==Nil)
    {
        reqList = [[RequestList alloc]initWithNibName:@"RequestList" bundle:nil];
    }

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:reqList animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: but i initialized it in another place so it non-zero/ not nil and it still doesn't work

Comment: What is you view setup? Do you have the UINavigationController as the root view controller and within a view you have a tab bar controller or the tab bar controller is the root view controller and one of the tab item is the uinavigationController?

Comment: i have the tab bar controller as the root view controller i set an array of two view controllers (one table view and one view controller ) as the tab bar controller's view controllers. In the init and initWithStyle methods in the two view controllers I made a uibaritem.